# Spring Boot hook point / event after database connected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We have a Spring Boot 2.6 application with a PostgreSQL database. We use all the default database mechanisms (connection is defined in config via `spring.datasource.*` etc) - nothing special here.

Now we are looking for a hook point after the database connection was set up. We need to perform some checks before rest of the beans are loaded.

```
1. Spring start
2. Connect database
#. { hook point - to perform some db things }
3. Startup of other beans (which also rely on database)
```

Which hook point / Spring event / what else can we use to perform our checks?

Comment: I just realized that `DataSourceSchemaCreatedEvent` would be exactly what I need but it way removed in Spring 2.5

Comment: My organization uses PostgreSQL, we're considering using Spring, and we want to run a  "SET application_name" statement on all connections.  By default, Spring uses Hikari for pooling.  Hikari has a "init sql" configuration parameter which it executes on all connections it creates, which solve the problem for my use case.  You might be able to do this purely configuration, but I had to write a DataSource bean, cast the return value of DataSourceBuilder to a HikariDataSource, and then invoke setConnectionInitSql with my custom SQL.